# Is it OK if I used plist? iOS

Tags: ios, plist, data-management

I need to save about 14 `NSDictionaries` to a plist. Each Dictionary is going to have 5 item. 1- name of the place
2- starting  time
3- finishing time
4- Total
5- Additional notes
I've been reading and people are advising against using plist for large amount of data. With the description given above is it wise to use plist?
Cheers,
Sma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what number of dictionaries would be considered "large" in this case, but it would be measured in the thousands. The big concern would be the amount of RAM the plist's objects consume when read into memory. 14 dictionaries containing small objects like you describe won't take up much at all.

The big benefit of using something like CoreData instead would be the ability to fetch small subsets of your data without having to load all your items and their contents. This saves RAM and also makes random access tasks like search more pleasant. (and CoreData also give you some nice freebies like undo support). But it seems like even up to 1000 items, it'd just as quick to read everything into RAM and sort it out there.

Answer (score 5):

That's not a large amount of data.

Comment: Thanks. It just wasn't clear how much was too much. What's considered large amount or data?

Answer (score 1):

Even one suggestion you can have multiple dictionary in single plist file inside an array/dictionary itself.

Comment: How can I grab that structure and populate a tableview with it. Because that is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Please check the ans added below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example:

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>NAME1</string>
        <key>Address</key>
        <string>ADD1</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>NAME2</string>
        <key>Address</key>
        <string>ADD2</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Here I have created array of dictionaries. So firstly I will read entire array then I will fetch the value for particular data which is needed (for example: Object at Index-1). So it will return me only one dictionary. Then array can be released and use that dictionary by key-value pair.

You can achieve the same by creating dictionary of dictionaries if your internal dictionary structure is different for all. For that you will require to fetch particular data using by its key name.

Hope this will be helpful for you.  Isn't it?